# Unwrapping error connecting UITbale view to firebase real time database

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am truing to get a UITableview to read video from firebase database.
I have connected to firebase data base. set up my data base as shown:

[image]

I set up a structure and linked and have the videos linked to it. 
The app reads the database title fine but when i go to click on the individual cells that link directly to the videos i am getting an unwrapping error.

[image]

So the table view is populated with the title video 1 and video 2 but for some reason these cells arent reading the link to the video file stored in firebase.

The structure I set up is: 
[image]

The code in the viewcontroller.swift is:

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
 var table = [Videos]()
var ref: DatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var Tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("videos")
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.table.removeAll()

            for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let Object = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let Title =  Object?["Title"]
                let videolink = Object?["link"]

                let video = Videos(Title: Title as? String, link: video as? String)
                self.table.append(video)

                self.Tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return table.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    let video: Videos
    video = table[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = video.Title
    return cell 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: table[indexPath.row].link!) else {
        return
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }   
}
}
```

The only other thing I have is a TableViewCell.swift file:

[image]

its a fairly simple project but I am stuck somehow. if anyone can see where i am going wrong that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is at this line:

```
let video = Videos(Title: Title as? String, link: video as? String)
```

It should be:

```
let video = Videos(Title: Title as? String, link: videolink as? String)
```

Hope this helps.